# Can you have an INNER JOIN without the ON keyword?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g

While debugging into some Oracle code, I came across this query:

```
SELECT TPM_TASK.TASKID FROM TPM_GROUP 
INNER JOIN TPM_USERGROUPS ON TPM_GROUP.GROUPID = TPM_USERGROUPS.GROUPID 
INNER JOIN TPM_TASK
INNER JOIN TPM_GROUPTASKS ON TPM_TASK.TASKID = TPM_GROUPTASKS.TASKID 
INNER JOIN TPM_PROJECTVERSION ON TPM_TASK.PROJECTID = TPM_PROJECTVERSION.PROJECTID AND TPM_TASK.VERSIONID = TPM_PROJECTVERSION.VERSIONID 
INNER JOIN TPM_TASKSTAGE ON TPM_TASK.STAGEID = TPM_TASKSTAGE.STAGEID 
INNER JOIN TPM_PROJECTSTAGE ON TPM_PROJECTVERSION.STAGEID = TPM_PROJECTSTAGE.STAGEID 
ON TPM_GROUP.GROUPID = TPM_GROUPTASKS.GROUPID
```

I'm confused by the line:

```
INNER JOIN TPM_TASK
```

I haven't seen a `JOIN` without an `ON` clause before.  Also confusing is the line:

```
ON TPM_GROUP.GROUPID = TPM_GROUPTASKS.GROUPID
```

This seems like a random `ON` clause without any matching `JOIN`.  The query runs without any errors, and returns a bunch of data, so obvious the syntax is perfectly valid.  Can someone shed some light on exactly what's going on here?

Comment: As a side note, in case anyone is searching how to CREATE a join without an ON clause (like I was), you can use 'CROSS JOIN' to do this, which returns the Cartesian product.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Small universe... I ran across a tool generating this syntax yesterday and was rather flummoxed.

Apparently,

```
FROM a 
     INNER JOIN b
     INNER JOIN c ON (b.id = c.id)
     ON (a.id = c.id)
```

is equivalent to a nested subquery

```
FROM a
     INNER JOIN (SELECT <<list of columns>>
                   FROM b
                        INNER JOIN c ON (b.id=c.id)) c
             ON (a.id = c.id)
```

Comment: Ok, if this syntax flummoxed the great Justin Cave, then I definitely don't feel too bad.  I'll play around with it on some simpler queries so I fully understand.  Thanks!

Comment: Y'know I've been staring at this for ages, and I can't get it. I think my confusion is around the use of `c` as a table and as an alias for the subquery. Is that a typo or typical usage?

Comment: @NeilBarnwell - It's not a typo.  I believe I structured the aliases this way because `c` in the original query is used as both the table and the, effectively, the alias for the subquery.  You could write the same thing with the subquery aliased to `d` and the join condition `a.id = d.id`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know you could do that, because how would it know you meant the alias c, or the actual table c? I guess there's a priority thing going on, where I would expect some sort of ambiguous reference error.

Answer (score 5):

I think that this is only a problem of ordering your query (since there are only `INNER JOIN`s, the order of them is not really that important). I rearrenged your query and now it looks like this:

```
SELECT TPM_TASK.TASKID 
FROM TPM_GROUP 
INNER JOIN TPM_USERGROUPS 
    ON TPM_GROUP.GROUPID = TPM_USERGROUPS.GROUPID 
INNER JOIN TPM_GROUPTASKS 
    ON TPM_GROUP.GROUPID = TPM_GROUPTASKS.GROUPID
INNER JOIN TPM_TASK
    ON TPM_TASK.TASKID = TPM_GROUPTASKS.TASKID 
INNER JOIN TPM_PROJECTVERSION 
    ON TPM_TASK.PROJECTID = TPM_PROJECTVERSION.PROJECTID 
    AND TPM_TASK.VERSIONID = TPM_PROJECTVERSION.VERSIONID 
INNER JOIN TPM_TASKSTAGE 
    ON TPM_TASK.STAGEID = TPM_TASKSTAGE.STAGEID 
INNER JOIN TPM_PROJECTSTAGE 
    ON TPM_PROJECTVERSION.STAGEID = TPM_PROJECTSTAGE.STAGEID
```

Does it make more sense to you now?, it does to me.

Answer (score 4):

It'd look fine if it had parenthesis in there...

```
SELECT TPM_TASK.TASKID 
FROM 
    TPM_GROUP 
    INNER JOIN TPM_USERGROUPS ON TPM_GROUP.GROUPID = TPM_USERGROUPS.GROUPID 
    INNER JOIN (
        TPM_TASK
        INNER JOIN TPM_GROUPTASKS ON TPM_TASK.TASKID = TPM_GROUPTASKS.TASKID 
        INNER JOIN TPM_PROJECTVERSION ON TPM_TASK.PROJECTID = TPM_PROJECTVERSION.PROJECTID 
            AND TPM_TASK.VERSIONID = TPM_PROJECTVERSION.VERSIONID 
        INNER JOIN TPM_TASKSTAGE ON TPM_TASK.STAGEID = TPM_TASKSTAGE.STAGEID 
        INNER JOIN TPM_PROJECTSTAGE ON TPM_PROJECTVERSION.STAGEID = TPM_PROJECTSTAGE.STAGEID 
    ) ON TPM_GROUP.GROUPID = TPM_GROUPTASKS.GROUPID
```

but since they are all inner joins I agree with Lamak's answer.