# I don't understand a FROM clause with ON in an unexpected place

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have inherited a query.  It is the product of some query designer.  The form of the query is:

```
select stuff
    from a
        join b
        join c on b.k = c.k
        join d on c.j = d.j
        on a.l = d.l
            and a.m = d.m
        join e on a.n = e.n
```

I expect a join to be `join t1 on t1.f = t0.f`, like the second, third, and fourth lines with 'join'.  I don't know how I am supposed to read this query with a table that doesn't have a 'on' right after it, and later, two 'on's in a row.

But server doesn't mind.  It returns a data set of stuff that has served us well, until now when we want to change the stuff we are selecting.   How is the server parsing this?

TIA

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856016/can-you-have-an-inner-join-without-the-on-keyword) might be helpful to you.  I believe the missing `ON` clause will cause your query to be interpreted as having a nested subquery.

Comment: There is no nested query here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will understand the query better with parentheses:

```
select stuff
from a join
     (b join
      c
      on b.k = c.k join
      d
      on c.j = d.j
     )
     on a.l = d.l and a.m = d.m join
     e
     on a.n = e.n
```

With inner joins, the parentheses don't matter.  Such logic can matter with outer joins, but frankly, I have never found it necessary.  I find any use of `join` without a subsequent `on` to be hard to follow.

Comment: I don't suppose there is some official documentation of how TSQL doesn't need parentehses in this case?

Comment: @SkipSaillors . . . If you read the grammar carefully, you'll see that a join is `table_source "join" table_source on conditions`.  `table_source` in turn can be a table or a join expression (or a bunch of other things).  Hence, the grammar does describe this syntax.

Answer (score 1):

It could help if you imagine SQL Server is implying some parenthesis in your query e.g.

```
select stuff
from a
    join 
    (
        b
        join c on b.k = c.k
        join d on c.j = d.j
    )
    on a.l = d.l and a.m = d.m
    join e on a.n = e.n
```

Which is like saying "Join a to the the result of: b joined to c joined to d. And then join e".

Bear in mind that the join operation is commutative, that is the order of joins does not make any difference to the result set.  The query optimizer usually rearranges the joins to get the best-performing physical join order.  You can look at the execution plan to see what actual physical join order is selected.

Anyway now you need to change it feel free to re-write in a more easily understood form e.g.

```
select stuff
from b
join c on b.k = c.k   
join d on c.j = d.j
join a on a.l = d.l and a.m = d.m
join e on a.n = e.n
```